# LDAP Authentication Provider not working with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to create user in GeoServer using LDAP.

The user is create in Apache Directory studio (see the picture 2 for the configuration)

Here is my configuration in GeoServer(see Picture1.png attached to this mail)

The GeoServer is getting error when I try to connect with the LDAP user created:

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onRequest of interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1@da8d64f on component [TestLink [Component id = test]] threw an exception
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:268)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doPost(WicketServlet.java:159)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:328)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor488.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    ... 117 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource
    at org.geoserver.security.ldap.LDAPUtils.createLdapContext(LDAPUtils.java:29)
    at org.geoserver.security.ldap.LDAPSecurityProvider.createAuthenticationProvider(LDAPSecurityProvider.java:64)
    at org.geoserver.web.security.ldap.LDAPAuthProviderPanel$TestLDAPConnectionPanel$TestLink.doTest(LDAPAuthProviderPanel.java:275)
    at org.geoserver.web.security.ldap.LDAPAuthProviderPanel$TestLDAPConnectionPanel$TestLink.onSubmit(LDAPAuthProviderPanel.java:256)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1.onSubmit(AjaxSubmitLink.java:111)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior$AjaxFormSubmitter.onSubmit(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:218)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:787)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:174)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
    ... 121 more
An error occurred while loading the page
```

[image]

---

I used Java 18
see the screenshort attached[image]

Comment: which version of java are you running GeoServer with?

Comment: I used Java 18 . see  the screenshort attached

Comment: GeoServer is tested against Java 11 and experimentally against Java 17 - so I would guess it doesn't work with Java 18

Comment: So i should use Java version 11 or 8 right? as mentionned in this page:https://docs.geoserver.org/2.22.x/en/user/production/java.html. My geoserver version  is 2.22